# Gulp to version filename and replace links

Tags: gulp, vulcanize

For any URL which doesn't start with `/static`, I serve this `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="import" href="/app.html">
</head>
...
</html>
```

**Note:** the `/` in `/app.html` to ensure it always serves `app.html` from the root.

I wish to run gulp/vulcanize over `app.html` to:

- create a bundle which sits in: `/static/<version-or-timestampp-or-hash-here>/app.html`
- change the import in `index.html` to point to the the above generated bundle

I currently have the following gulp file that will do the vulcanize, but it won't do the versioning or change `index.html` link:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var vulcanize = require('gulp-vulcanize');

gulp.task('vulcanize', function() {
    return gulp.src(['app.html'])
        .pipe(vulcanize({
            stripComments: true,
            inlineScripts: true,
            inlineCss: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('static'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['vulcanize']);
```

How do I achieve the two points above?